# How do you get the URI from request object in Django?

Tags: django, uri

How do you get the URI from request object in Django?

Is there request.uri?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
request.META['REQUEST_URI']
```

or

```
request.get_full_path()
```

You tend to generate a flood of trivial questions, answers to which you could easily find in documentation/Google...

Comment: Update, on Django 1.7 using ```request.path_info``` trivial yes, the docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/

Comment: Another quick debugging option is to add print(dir(request)) in your view.

Comment: Author doesn't understand role that stack overflow plays in googling process, then patronizes asker

Comment: @cdosborn It happened more than 8 years ago, but I still remember this. For a couple of days, the list of newest Django questions was utterly dominated by a flood of very low effort questions from the same author, who clearly treated SO as if it was Google. Adding a question every couple of minutes, apparently not doing any research himself nor carrying to properly format his questions (this question is presentable only because the community later edited it - look at its history). On StackOverflow, a degree of effort is expected from both people writing answers and people asking questions.

Comment: @cdosborn It was the only time during my entire time on StackOverflow that I felt compelled to comment on someone's behavior - I felt at the time that the situation became disruptive and interfered with our ability to answer other questions properly. I still feel I was pretty measured in my reaction, considering everything.

Comment: As someone who found your answer useful (the first hit on google ironically), I could care less about the asker's history. I could care that you volunteered to answer only to denounce the question as trivial. It is a mistake to consider such questions a waste of time. StackO links information (in the form of answers) to actual questions that people have in a way that docs cannot. Also consider that while (validly) intending to the correct the behavior of one, you've patronized other visitors that came with the same "trivial" question.

Answer (score 0):

In django 3.2 there is no `request.META['REQUEST_URI']` as it is in answer above.

Easiest way is to print Meta data, and find what you need:

```
print(request.META)
```

This is how i solved this problem:

For example requested url will be:

```
https://example.com/first_folder/nice_page/
```

Get `domain` - `(example.com)`:

```
domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
# its will output:
# example.com
```

Get `path` - `/first_folder/nice_page/`:

```
path = request.META['PATH_INFO']
# or 
path = request.get_full_path()
# both of this options will have the same output:
# /first_folder/nice_page/
```

Get `protocol` - `http://` or `https://`

```
protocol = request.META['wsgi.url_scheme']
# this will output:
# http   or   https
```

So your `full path` may be like this:

```
protocol = request.META['wsgi.url_scheme']    
domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
path = request.META['PATH_INFO']

full_path = protocol + "://" + domain + path

# it's output will be:
# https://example.com/first_folder/nice_page/
```