# How to get URI template in django?

Tags: django

I need to get original uri template with regex from resolve function in view or middleware. For example:

```
def view(request):
    uri_path = resolve(request...)
    # and uri_path must be equals something like 'articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/'
    ...
```

Is this possible? I didn't found information about this

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/25675398/6427186 https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673115/6427186

Comment: @Md.NahidurRahman, no, there is no answer. There is just reverse function usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for `PATH_INFO` from the request object.

Try this -

```
request.META['PATH_INFO']
```

You can look for other info present at request META -

```
meta = request.META
for k, v in meta.items():
    print(f"{k}\t{v}")
```

To get the resolve path, try below -

```
from django.urls import resolve

r = resolve(request.META['PATH_INFO'])
print(r.route) # will print like /office/employee/<int:eid>
```

[Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

Answer (score 0):

So, i've found what i've searching for - [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch.route). But the problem is that this API new in django 2.2, i have an older django